# How to call parent non virtual function in c++ multi inheritance?

Tags: c++

```
class VA {
 public:
  virtual void print() = 0;
};
class VB : public VA {
 public:
  virtual void bprint() = 0;
};
class SA : public VA {
 public:
  void print() override { std::cout << "SA" << std::endl; };
};
class SB : public SA, public VB {
 public:
  virtual void bprint() { std::cout << "SB" << std::endl; };
};
int main() {
  SB sb;
  sb.bprint();
  sb.print();
}
```

What is the correct way to call sb.print()?

```
class SB : public SA, public VB {
 public:
  virtual void bprint() { std::cout << "SB" << std::endl; };
  void print() override { SA::print(); };
};
```

I know this kind of override will work, but I am considering is there a way that no extra code in `class SB`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to make `VA` an interface in Java sense: no data, only some methods which have to be implemented only once in the hierarchy.

Short version: use virtual inheritance for `VA`: `: public virtual VA`.

Long version follows.

Multiple inheritance in C++ by default creates independent paths to all base objects. In your case, `SB` actually has *two* `VA` bases: one from `SA`, and one from `VB`. The former has an implementation of `print`, the latter does not, hence the first compilation error:

```
a.cpp: In function 'int main()':
a.cpp:20:6: error: cannot declare variable 'sb' to be of abstract type 'SB'
   20 |   SB sb;
      |      ^~
a.cpp:15:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within 'SB':
   15 | class SB : public SA, public VB {
      |       ^~
a.cpp:5:16: note:     'virtual void VA::print()'
    5 |   virtual void print() = 0;
      |                ^~~~~
a.cpp:22:6: error: request for member 'print' is ambiguous
   22 |   sb.print();
      |      ^~~~~
a.cpp:5:16: note: candidates are: 'virtual void VA::print()'
    5 |   virtual void print() = 0;
      |                ^~~~~
a.cpp:13:8: note:                 'virtual void SA::print()'
   13 |   void print() override { std::cout << "SA" << std::endl; };
      |        ^~~~~
```

However, there is also the second error. It becomes more visible if you implement `print` both in `SA` and `VB`: there are actually two `print`s:

```
a.cpp: In function 'int main()':
a.cpp:23:6: error: request for member 'print' is ambiguous
   23 |   sb.print();
      |      ^~~~~
a.cpp:5:16: note: candidates are: 'virtual void VA::print()'
    5 |   virtual void print() = 0;
      |                ^~~~~
a.cpp:10:8: note:                 'virtual void VB::print()'
   10 |   void print() override { std::cout << "VB" << std::endl; };  // Tried to add another implementation
      |        ^~~~~
a.cpp:14:8: note:                 'virtual void SA::print()'
   14 |   void print() override { std::cout << "SA" << std::endl; };
      |        ^~~~~
```

In C++ corresponding mechanics is provided by virtual inheritance: every base which should be deduplicated should be marked as `virtual`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class VA {
 public:
  virtual void print() = 0;
};
class VB : public virtual VA {  // 'virtual' ~ 'please ensure there is only one VA base'
 public:
  virtual void bprint() = 0;
};
class SA : public virtual VA {  // 'virtual' ~ 'please ensure there is only one VA base'
 public:
  void print() override { std::cout << "SA" << std::endl; };
};
class SB : public SA, public VB {
 public:
  virtual void bprint() { std::cout << "SB" << std::endl; };
};
int main() {
  SB sb;
  sb.bprint();
  sb.print();
}
```

Now the compiler knows that there is only one `VA` base, and successfully finds its `print` implementation unambiguously in `SA`. It's important that `SA` is derived from `VA`, though, otherwise `SA::print` won't have any connection to `VA::print` whatsoever.